# In two-way TLS Handshake, Why Client Required to Provide Private Key

Tags: authentication, ssl

1. In most of the online sources, I was told that in the two way TLS,
   the client needs to provide the cert for the server to validate. My
   case is that the device gets the cert from the CA, but when the
   device attempt establish a tls connection, the pfx is required which
   will contain the private key from the device.
2. I have used openssl to convert the pfx to .cert and .key. By only using the .cert part on
   POSTMAN, I failed to connect to the server with 403. Only when I
   include both .key and .cert the TLS 1.2 connection was established. 
   For the regular TLS (one-way), the private key will never be sent
   from the server, but why is the client need to send pfx.

Comment: Private keys are never exchanged over TLS (at least in the handshake part) because otherwise, by definition, they won't be private any more... But for a party to prove it is really the owner of a given certificate, it will need to use (locally) its private key to sign something that the other party will be able to check with the certificate as it basically contains the public key associated to the private one.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. You should start by some introduction reading on the TLS handshake such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake   Note also that filenames and even extensions ARE NOT RELEVANT. We (humans) name them in order for things to be simple for us, but the computer does not care. What is relevant is the content and how it is encoded. You can name the file with your key `foobar.43` and the one with your certificate `I_AM_A_CERTIFICATE.no.really.I.AM` and it will work as well (except in brain dead OS/software)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks a lot, I think I get it now that the the private key is needed in both POST/ or httpclient not to sent but to use for CertificateVerify message indicates client owns the cert.  Thanks again for the help and I will learn on the formatting and what to ask here as well. Thank you.

Comment: TLS stuff happens before any HTTP related stuff indeed.